# Is it possible to set WCF Service Contract Name to empty?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a legacy soap client and I need to construct the soap service. There are two SOAPActions the client expects /connect and /disconnect. I have an interface called IProto which has two functions connect and disconnect. The problem is that WCF prepends Service contract name (IProto) in SOAPAction and the client cannot locate the expecting actions. For example service SOAPAction IProto/connect and IProto/disconnect and the client expects /connect and /disconnect. 
Is there any way to set service contract name to empty?

PS. Legacy client source code cannot be altered.

Comment: Of 8 questions with answers you have marked two as answered, despite two of your questions receiving 8 responses each. Perhaps you should consider going back and awarding the answers.

Comment: Setting name to "" throws an exception.  How do I set name to ""?

Answer (score 3):

So you don't want to set the ServiceContract name to empty, you want to alter the SOAPAction. Asking the right question brings you halfway to a solution.

Look at the `Action` member of the [OperationContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
[OperationContract(Action="/connect")]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [ServiceContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute_properties.aspx) attribute has properties you can set to achieve this.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "***", Namespace = "***")]
```

Comment: Name cannot be empty here it throws an exception

Comment: I can not set name to something else in the legacy client and I dont have access to its source code. It just expects /connect for SOAPAction and my service exposes IProto/connect

Answer (score 0):

Replace the default implementation of [IDispatchOperationSelector](http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/wcf-extensions-idispatchoperationselector/)?

Comment: Note: this is the complicated way of doing `OperationContract`.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
public interface IMyServiceContract
```

Comment: Then set name to empty aswell.

Comment: setting name to empty throws an exception

Comment: Then I guess it's not possible?